# Getting error during update ad creatives by FB marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I am using Facebook marketing API for update adcreatives but I am getting below error.

> {"error":{"message":"Invalid
> parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":1815573,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Failed
> to update the creative","error_user_msg":"Failed to update creative
> 6,060,290,455,919. Please specify name, status or associated adlabels
> for updating the creative.","fbtrace_id":"AZj1cjgCsX7DcTVUvMLJCo-"}}

My code is:

```
try{
            $object_story_spec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
            $object_story_spec->setData(array(
            AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => '<page_id>',
            AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA => $link_data,
            ));
                   
            $creative = new AdCreative("<adcreativeid>");
            $creative->setData(array(
                AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec
            ));
            $creative->updateSelf();
        }catch (\FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException $e) {
            print_r($e->getResponse()->getBody());
        }
```

Comment: we are getting the same cryptic message. did you ever figure this out?  what are these random numbers in the message: "Failed to update creative 120,330,000,480,705,703. Please specify name, status or associated adlabels for updating the creative."

Comment: We were getting this message because our ad account was in unsettled state.
check your payment setting.

Answer (score 1):

Because update of those fields are not allowed. You can check the same in [Developer Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/#Updating).

Only fields that can be updated are `name,status,adlabels,account_id`.